Short read of DER length Error - Release build Android (Java)
Using the login credentials I used to upload a build to the Google Play interface before, I'm attempting to create a release build.
However, it is giving me the error Short read of DER length after a few upgrades.
I attempted to use the project's Git history to revert to the previous package name, but the error persisted.
What would be the probable cause of this?
Moreover, how can I complete this (make a release build) with the previous package name OR previous login credentials?

Most likely "DER length" is referring to a certificate or cryptographic key/signature which is saved in ASN.1 DER format. Therefore my guess would be the upload certificate (assuming you upload a signed Android bundle and not an APK file). Try to generate a new upload certificate as documented by Google.
